# I can't access nested JavaScript function in index.jsp

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsp

I have a function that is supposed to perform pagination on a table. Within that function is another function that needs to be executed when I click on the numbers in the navigation bar. The code works fine in VSCode. When I put the code in `index.jsp` in eclipse, the function gives the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: sort is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick`.

```
// get the table element
var table = document.getElementById("disposalTable"),
// number of rows per page
n = 5,
// number of rows of the table
rowCount = table.rows.length,
// get the first cell's tag name (in the first row)
firstRow = table.rows[0].firstElementChild.tagName,
// boolean var to check if table has a head row
hasHead = (firstRow === "TH"),
// an array to hold each row
tr = [],
// loop counters, to start count from rows[1] (2nd row) if the first row has a head tag
i,ii,j = (hasHead)?1:0,
// holds the first row if it has a (<TH>) & nothing if (<TD>)
th = (hasHead?table.rows[(0)].outerHTML:"");
// count the number of pages
var pageCount = Math.ceil(rowCount / n);
// if we had one page only, then we have nothing to do ..
if (pageCount > 1) {
    // assign each row outHTML (tag name & innerHTML) to the array
    for (i = j,ii = 0; i < rowCount; i++, ii++)
    tr[ii] = table.rows[i].outerHTML;
    // create a div block to hold the buttons
    table.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend","<div id='buttons'></div");
    // the first sort, default page is the first one
    sort(1);
}

// ($p) is the selected page number. it will be generated when a user clicks a button
function sort(p) {
    /* create ($rows) a variable to hold the group of rows
    ** to be displayed on the selected page,
    ** ($s) the start point .. the first row in each page, Do The Math
    */
    var rows = th,s = ((n * p)-n);
    for (i = s; i < (s+n) && i < tr.length; i++)
    rows += tr[i];
    
    // now the table has a processed group of rows ..
    table.innerHTML = rows;
    // create the pagination buttons
    document.getElementById("buttons").innerHTML = pageButtons(pageCount,p);
    // CSS Stuff
    document.getElementById("id"+p).setAttribute("class","active");
}


// ($pCount) : number of pages,($cur) : current page, the selected one ..
function pageButtons(pCount,cur) {
    /* this variables will disable the "Prev" button on 1st page
        and "next" button on the last one */
    var prevDis = (cur == 1)?"disabled":"",
    nextDis = (cur == pCount)?"disabled":"",
    /* this ($buttons) will hold every single button needed
    ** it will creates each button and sets the onclick attribute
    ** to the "sort" function with a special ($p) number..
    */
    buttons = "<input type='button' value='&lt;&lt; Prev' onclick='sort("+(cur - 1)+")' "+prevDis+">";
    for (i=1; i<=pCount;i++)
    buttons += "<input type='button' id='id"+i+"'value='"+i+"' onclick='sort("+i+")'>";
    buttons += "<input type='button' value='Next &gt;&gt;' onclick='sort("+(cur + 1)+")' "+nextDis+">";
    return buttons;
}
```

Comment: Does it work when running the page?

Comment: Yes it does execute, but when I click on the number 2 button to go to the next page, it does not want to execute.

Comment: Was there an error message in the browser's console?

Comment: Yes - error: Uncaught ReferenceError: sort is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Instead of trying to access the nested function. Put the pager code into a function. Then create an instance of the function as a variable. And call that variable every time.

For instance:

let pager = new Pager();

Then the onclick method will call pager.sort(1) or pager.sort(2) everytime.